# Why is this double value printed as "-0"?

Tags: c++

```
double a = 0;
double b = -42;
double result = a * b;
cout << result;
```

The result of `a * b` is `-0`, but I expected `0`. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: I believe 0 == -0 so there is no problem. -0 is a floating point issue.

Comment: The [wikipedia article on Signed zero](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_zero) is worth a read.

Comment: I've edited the title to make it more specific.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The bit *representation* of `-0.0` and `0.0` are **different**, but they are **same value**, so `-0.0==0.0` would return `true`. In your case, `result` is `-0.0`, because one of the operand is negative.

See this demo:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

void print_bytes(char const *name, double d)
{
    unsigned char *pd = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(&d);
    std::cout << name << " = " << std::setw(2) << d << " => ";
    for(int i = 0 ; i < sizeof(d) ; ++i)
       std::cout << std::setw(-3) << (unsigned)pd[i] << " ";
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

#define print_bytes_of(a) print_bytes(#a, a)

int main()
{
    double a = 0.0;
    double b = -0.0;

    std::cout << "Value comparison" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "(a==b) => " << (a==b)  <<std::endl;
    std::cout << "(a!=b) => " << (a!=b)  <<std::endl;


    std::cout << "\nValue representation" << std::endl;
    print_bytes_of(a);
    print_bytes_of(b);
}
```

Output ([demo@ideone](http://ideone.com/0dR33z)):

```
Value comparison
(a==b) => 1
(a!=b) => 0

Value representation
a =  0 => 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
b = -0 => 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 128
```

As you can see yourself, the *last* byte of `-0.0` is different from the *last* byte of `0.0`.

Hope that helps.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754#Formats

"Zero values are finite values with significand 0. These are signed zeros, the sign bit specifies if a zero is +0 (positive zero) or −0 (negative zero)."

Comment: floating point comparisons `==` and `!=` are unsafe. Never ever do this.

Comment: @Walter: In this context, they're not. I'm comparing a *value* with itself.

Comment: @Walter - floating point comparisons are well-defined and useful. Programmers who are afraid of them have been burned because they don't understand what their calculations are doing, not because there's anything bad about equality comparisons.

Comment: I don't believe that C++ *requires* a distinction between positive and negative floating-point zero, but it does permit it.

Comment: @Walter: They are not "unsafe" whatsoever. You are repeating a mantra, and doing so incorrectly.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit okay, they are not "safe" in the sense that they don't cause traps etc, but they don't necessarily do what you think they should, because of truncation from 80 to 64 or 32 bits: the result of a 80bit floating point operation may differ from another 80bit floating point operation, but their 64bit or 32bit representations may look the same.

Comment: @Walter: Which is no problem at all for comparing `0` with `-0` (value comparisons aren't dumb bitwise checks), or indeed for practically any other real number. That is, there is an _enormous_ set of floating-point value pairs for which `==` and `!=` is _just fine_; "never ever do this" is alarmist and harmful.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit sigh. It's not at all about *floating-point values* and how they compare. It's about any internal intermediate (80-bit) representation, which the compiler is at liberty to use instead of the *floating-point value* of 64 bits. The 80bit representations may compare differently than the 64 bit representations. I once had this causing my program to fail ... that's why I stopped using floating-point comparisons (you may have also noticed that most compilers warn about this when using the full set of warning flags).

Comment: @Walter: _It doesn't matter_. `0` will compare favourably with `-0`, in all cases.

Comment: Why exactly is the last byte different?

Comment: @0x499602D2: It is because of different representation of `-0.0`. The last indicates it is negative representation.